# When press on Back Button, Fragment Animation does not work properly in Android

Tags: android

I am using `Fragment`,when i have to move on next `Fragment`. I replace the `Fragment`, but when I press Back Button animation does not appear properly. Is there anyone tell me,how I can set animation.

**My Fragment**

```
fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();    
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_out,R.anim.slide_enter,R.anim.slide_exit);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**My Back Button**

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();

        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
            {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();                     
                 return true;

             }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: normally you have the fragmentManager who is in charge internally of pop back the stack on back button's press. I can't see why you are doing this again. Try deleting that, if not show yours animation's xml files

Comment: The animation files are okey. Another solution please

Comment: Did you remove the keylistener ? the way to set your animations is well.

Comment: No,Back button click is working.

Comment: Setting that listener in onResume is potentially useless

Comment: If u have any solution,then tell??